Creating a table visual in Power BI with Deneb
I need to create a Table structure in Power BI with Deneb and vega or vega lite with two columns - Report Name in the first column and then a View button in the next column with the link to the report. Im new to deneb and am finding it very difficult. Can anyone help me please.
I managed to make a simple structure but can't really format it as a proper table with horizontal lines separating each row and it looks kind of too simple and underdone.

Someone please help me.

What is the reason for not using the native Power Bi table visual?
And please add your spec including the data to your question and an image or similar to show what you would like to achieve. Best practice is to use the vega online editor for an example
